# change all existing collation of columns

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a table which some of its columns has collation of utf8_bin. But I need to change them to utf8_unicode_ci. 
I know this query for do it:

```
ALTER TABLE  `shn_sho_cities` CHANGE  `city_name`  `city_name` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL ;
```

but as I want change all columns which have utf8_bin instead of writing a query for each column. 
Is there any way which I could do this?

Comment: Check out the syntax of `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO ...`

Answer (score 4):

The following code will generate the required queries to change your collations, to `utf8mb4` with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME,'` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 
utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;') AS    mySQL
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA= "YOU-DB-NAME"
AND TABLE_TYPE="BASE TABLE"
```